# login entries in OSX keychain reappear after a few minutes. How to delete permanently?

Tags: macos, keychain

I'm on OSX 10.8.2. I have entries in my login keychain from a previous employer's network that I wish to delete. After selecting these and deleting them, they reappear after a few minutes!
How do I permanently get rid of these entries?

Edit 1: I ran Keychain first Aid with no issues found.

Comment: Do you use iCloud or other syncing software e.g. via Dropbox?

Comment: I am using iCloud